# I have 2 forms, the first form contains read only information, how do I update it using the second form input box with a link tag for submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I have 2 forms, containing employee information that is `readOnly=true`
My second form contains, input box to replace and update the data inside the first form. My update is a link tag instead of button.

**1st Form**

```
<form class="secondtdr" name="updatein">
                                    <h4 class="ua">Referrer Personal Information</h4>
                                            <div class="referrerid">
                                                <p align="left">Referrer ID</p>
                                                <input type="text" name="cont" value="<?php echo $contact_no; ?>" readOnly="true">
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="empnum">
                                                <p align="left">Employee Number</p>
                                                <input type="number" name="cont" value="<?php echo $empid; ?>" readOnly="true">
                                            </div>
```

**2nd Form**

```
<form class="tabletoedit" method="post">
                                                        <br>
                                                        <div class="empnum">
                                                            <p align="left">Employee Number</p><br>
                                                            <input type="number" name="cont" value="">
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="fnamep">
                                                        <p align="left">Fullname</p>
                                                        <input type="text" name="cont" value="">
                                                        </div>
 <div class="action_btns">
                                                            <div class="one_half">
                                                            <a href="javascript:document.forms['updatein'].submit()" class="upbtn" name="btnUpdate">Update</a>     
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </form>
```

Comment: what have you written so far? Show us some code.

Comment: Edited. Sorry about the codes I'm new to it

Comment: you can do it with jquery on change event of second form's textbox

Comment: the second form is in modal btw @kevin

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by writing some javascript codes,like this(codes below are not tested).

```
<script>
    function updateData()
    {
      document.getElementById('form1_employee_num').value = document.getElementById('employee_num').value;
...
     //if you wan to update the new data to database,you can use AJAX
    }
</script>
```

form 1

```
<form class="secondtdr" name="updatein">
     <h4 class="ua">Referrer Personal Information</h4>
          <div class="referrerid">
             <p align="left">Referrer ID</p>
             <input type="text" name="cont" value="<?php echo $contact_no; ?>" readOnly="true" id="form1_referrer_id">
          </div>

          <div class="empnum">
             <p align="left">Employee Number</p>
                <input type="number" name="cont" value="<?php echo $empid; ?>" readOnly="true" id="form1_employee_num">
          </div>
```

form2

```
<form class="tabletoedit" method="post">
    <br>
    <div class="empnum">
       <p align="left">Employee Number</p><br>
       <input type="number" name="cont" value="" id="employee_num">
    </div>

    <div class="fnamep">
       <p align="left">Fullname</p>
       <input type="text" name="cont" value="" id="fullname">
    </div>
    <div class="action_btns">
        <div class="one_half">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="upbtn" name="btnUpdate" onclick="updateData();">Update</a>     
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```